Does using a transaction for read queries provide benefits under Read Committed Isolation Level in PostgreSQL?
I'm using Prisma with PostgreSQL. As I read about the transaction isolations in PostgreSQL, I wondered if I am using transactions without any benefits or if I understood the subject correctly.
async getProductCounts(categoryIds: string[]): Promise<any> {
  const stats = await this.prisma.$transaction(async (tx) => {
    const productsWithPrice = await tx.product.findMany({
      where: {
        categoryId: {
          in: categoryIds,
        },
        price: {
          not: null,
        },
      },
    });

    const productsWithoutPrice = await tx.product.findMany({
      where: {
        categoryId: {
          in: categoryIds,
        },
        price: null,
      },
    });

    return {
      productsWithPrice,
      productsWithoutPrice,
    };
  });

  return stats;
}


Given that the Read Committed isolation level is used, does wrapping these read-only findMany operations in a transaction provide any benefits?
I understand that Read Committed will make the 2 read queries see different snapshots anyways, so why would one use transaction here?
I am asking this to understand the transaction subject in PostgreSQL better.
Would this be any different if the second query was an update? Thank you for your answers.

There is no good reasons to put two read-only statements in a single transaction on the read committed isolation level.
If only the second statement modifies data, there is still no good reason.
